# Dynamic grid on resize mainwindow

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, grid, resize

I'll start by explaining what I'm trying to accomplish. So I have a list with images and those images have a name. I'm trying to place these images (and their names beneath them) in a grid next to each other and I would like the grid to have extra columns/rows depending on the size of my main window.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOGwS.jpg)

What I have done so far is, I've added the following in my custom grid class to track the resizing of my mainwindow.

```
mainWindow = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
mainWindow.MainWindowResize += mainWindow_MainWindowResize;
```

In "mainWindow_MainWindowResize" I made the 'calculations' to add/remove extra columns or rows & this works fine, BUT I was wondering if there is a better way to do this (for example by just using xaml).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample using [UniformGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid(v=vs.110).aspx) in pure XAML

```
<UniformGrid Columns="5"
             Rows="3">
    <UniformGrid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyImageTemplate">
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                <TextBlock Text="Image Title"
                           DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                <Image Source="pr.png" />
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UniformGrid.Resources>
    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyImageTemplate}" />
    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyImageTemplate}" />
    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyImageTemplate}" />
    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyImageTemplate}" />
    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyImageTemplate}" />
    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyImageTemplate}" />
    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyImageTemplate}" />
    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyImageTemplate}" />
    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyImageTemplate}" />
    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyImageTemplate}" />
    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyImageTemplate}" />
    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyImageTemplate}" />
    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyImageTemplate}" />
    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyImageTemplate}" />
    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyImageTemplate}" />
</UniformGrid>
```

result

[image: result]

The above is just an example, you may adjust as needed